# Piping crunch into openssl

Tags: openssl

I am stuck on how to pipe the output of crunch into openssl, as in:

```
crunch 6 9 --stdout > openssl passwd -1 -salt bW2f - table -in
```

or

```
openssl passwd -1 -salt bW2f -table -in | crunch 6 9
```

The idea is to perform testing on determining the password or passphrase used to create the known hash without having to use a wordlist file.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You need a pipe, but you've inverted the order of the commands. Plus, you need to instruct openssl to read from standard input, and you've to split the output of crunch so that a single line at a time is passed to openssl.

There are various options; a possible solution, using xargs:

```
crunch 6 9 --stdout 2> /dev/null | xargs -n 1 openssl passwd -1 -salt bW2f stdin
```

Comment: Excellent solution, works just fine.  THANK YOU.  Gave a +1, but since I am new it did not show up publicly.